# Regexp to remove the last character in a URL string only if it equals /

Tags: regex, url, directory, parent

The goal is here to basically get a match in a URL string to give us the full URL up till the last parent folder.  So for example, if we had:

https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4, it would give us https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3 .

The same result should happen if we had a / at the end like this:

https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/

I think this regexp **`(/*.*/|$)`** gives us the URL up to the last /, so it does not work if the URL ends with a /.

If we had: https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.php .

It would return https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4 .

So basically, up till the last parent folder of another folder or file.  Note that the solution should work on any URL and not the specific one in this question.

Comment: Try `^(.*?)/[^/]+/?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/wvSMxg/1

Answer (score 0):

This one might solve it. Any expression ending with "/" followed by a string without "/"

```
^(.+\/)[^\/]+$
```

Comment: Don't think that worked.  Did you a specific online regexp to est it out?

Answer (score 0):

One could use

```
/.*[^\/]/
```

to extract the string

```
"https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4"
```

from

```
"https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"
```

By contrast, this regex extracts the entire string from the strings

```
"https://www.example.com/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.php"
```

and

```
"https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4"
```

Note that because regular expressions are by default *greedy*, there is no need for anchors. In this example `.*` in the regex will match all but the last forward slash, again, because it is greedy.

Alternatively, one could use a method that converts the last character of the string to an empty string if it is `"/"`, returning a new string, leaving the original string unchanged. The regex

```
/\/\z/
```

could be used to identify that character, if present. In Ruby one could write:

```
str = "https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"
str.sub(/\/\z/, '')
  #=> "https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4"
```

We can confirm the original string was unaffected:

```
str
  #=> "https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"
```